# How do I embed a gather environment within a custom environment?

Tags: environments

I've tried defining the following custom environment, but I get errors:

> \begin{gather} ended by \end{solution}
>   etc...

Here's a MWE showing my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\newenvironment{solution}{%  <-Solution
  \par\addvspace{1em}
  \itshape{Solution:}\par\begin{gather}}
  {\end{gather}\par\normalfont\hfill\qed\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}
    testing
  \end{gather}

  %% This does not work:
  \begin{solution}
    testing
  \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the command-form of the `gather` environment. That is, `\gather`...`\endgather` instead of `\begin{gather}`...`\end{gather}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\newenvironment{solution}{%  <-Solution
  \par\addvspace{1em}
  \textit{Solution:}\par\gather}
  {\endgather\par\normalfont\hfill\qed\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}%

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{gather}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{gather}
Some text
\begin{solution}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
\end{solution}
Some text
\end{document}
```

---

Addition by OP:

Ultimately I ended up using `gather` instead, but it works just the same... using `\gather` and `\endgather`. But I also wanted to find a way to get rid of the equation numbers. A bit of searching allowed me to find out that `\align*` and `\endalign*` do not work as expected, so instead you have to use `\csname align*\endcsname` and `\csname endalign*\endcsname`