# Trouble defining new environment with embedded gather

Tags: environments, amsmath

I looked at the solution to [How do I embed a gather environment within a custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100219/22413)  But things are still not working for me:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mygather}
  {%%
     \begin{minipage}{2in}
       \csname gather*\endcsname
  }{%%
       \csname endgather*\endcsname
     \end{minipage}%%
  }

\begin{document}

  \begin{mygather}
      y = x^{2} - 3x + 5
  \end{mygather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're using amsmath, the other answer used mathtools.  There was a question here about using `align` within a custom environment with amsmath, but I can't find it right now.  I think that the solution was to use the `environ` package.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: You might be referring to [Making a new environment combining `equation` and `split`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3169/5764).

Comment: @Werner That looks like the one I was thinking of.

Comment: you might want to take a look at the `gathered` environment defined in the `mathtools` package.  that's meant as a subsidiary environment, which `gather` is not.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I hadn't noticed I wasn't using `mathtools`.  Ultimately I've chosen to go with the `environ` package.

Answer (score 5):

The `\gather*` command sees that it is inside the `minipage` environment, and so looks ahead for  `\end{minipage}`. But that doesn't exist until `\end{mygather}` is executed, and so `\gather*` keeps looking. The following might work:

```
\newenvironment{mygather}
  {%%
     \minipage{2in}
       \csname gather*\endcsname
  }{%%
       \csname endgather*\endcsname
     \endminipage%%
  }
```

In this rewrite, the `\minipage` is not an environment. The enclosing environment is `mygather` and so `\gather*` looks ahead for `\end{mygather}`, and finds it. I say it "might work" because, although it compiles fine without errors in your MWE, I don't really know what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  That helps a great deal to understand why the code is failing.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `\csname gather*\endcsname`, `amsmath` is smart enough to know what environment's name it has been called in, so as to absorb all text until the corresponding `\end` command appears. With your code it determines to have been called in `minipage`, but it's not able to *see* `\end{minipage}`, that's buried inside the end code.

So, just like Dan proposes, you can use `\minipage` and `\endminipage`. But this will not give a good output (I added `\fbox` around it just to clearly show the problem):

[image]

Why's that? Because you're starting a paragraph with a display, which shouldn't be done.

A workaround is to back up by `\baselineskip`

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mygather}
  {%%
   \minipage{2in}
   \vspace{-\baselineskip}
   \csname gather*\endcsname
  }{%%
    \csname endgather*\endcsname
    \endminipage
  }

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{mygather}
      y = x^{2} - 3x + 5
  \end{mygather}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler way is

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mygather}
  {%%
   \minipage{2in}
   \centering$\!\gathered
  }{%%
    \endgathered$
    \endminipage
  }

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{mygather}
      y = x^{2} - 3x + 5
  \end{mygather}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've suggested a work around, but is there a better approach that can avoid starting with a display?  The whole point of the my table is to create a nice visual structure that seems rather difficult to achieve with an `align*` or other such math environments.

Comment: @A.Ellett `\centering$\gathered...\endgathered$`?