# set section environment to be math only, amsmath's begin{gather}

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, environments, amsmath

I want to create a small formulary, and for that virtually every line has to be math formulas. I use the `gather`-environment from the package `amsmath`, for example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}%fleqn for align left

\newcommand \ul \underline  %next 3 rows for subsection title underline
\newcommand{\tmpsection}[1]{}
\let\tmpsection=\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\tmpsection{\underline{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\subsection{PSM}
\begin{gather*}
      \ul{u_s} = r_s\ul{i_s} + \frac{d}{dt}\ul{\Psi_s}
      +j\omega_k\underline{\Psi_s}\\
      \ul{\Psi_s}=l_s\ul{i_s}+\ul{\Psi_m}\\
      \omega_m=\omega_s\\
      \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

It seemed a good idea to incorporate the `\begin{gather}` environment into `\subsection`, and for that the redefinition of `\subsection` by `\newcommand` seemed probable, but I haven't been able to figure out what keywords  to search for.

Only found redefinitions of text style so far, but is it possible to include a `\begin`-`\end` environment into `\subsection`?

If not, i could use [this environment shorthand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13042/defining-a-shorthand-for-amsmaths-align-environment-as-commands) i guess, but still..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Erhm, it is definitely not clear what it is you are asking

Comment: I want to get rid of the \begin{gather*} and \end{gather*} by somehow putting it into \subsection by \renewcommand

Comment: Do you want the entire `gather` math content to form part of the sectional title? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}%fleqn for align left
\let\ul=\underline
\newenvironment{Gather}[1]{\subsection{\underline{#1}}%
        \minipage{\textwidth}\csname gather*\endcsname}
        {\csname endgather*\endcsname \endminipage}

\begin{document}

\begin{Gather}{PSM}
      \ul{u_s} = r_s\ul{i_s} + \frac{d}{dt}\ul{\Psi_s}
      +j\omega_k\underline{\Psi_s}\\
      \ul{\Psi_s}=l_s\ul{i_s}+\ul{\Psi_m}\\
      \omega_m=\omega_s\\
\end{Gather}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

The trick with the nested `gather*` environment, and an explanation as to why it is necessary, comes from the answer to [trouble defining new environment with embedded gather](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180890/trouble-defining-new-environment-with-embedded-gather)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrew, that helped a lot!

My final solution, for reference is
(no section numbering, `\g` as environment shorthand):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}%fleqn for align left
\let\ul=\underline
\newenvironment{Gather}[1]{\subsection*{\underline{#1}}%
    \minipage{\textwidth}\csname gather*\endcsname}
    {\csname endgather*\endcsname \endminipage}

\newcommand{\g}[2]{\begin{Gather}{#1}#2\end{Gather}}

\begin{document}

\g{PSM}{
  \ul{u_s} = r_s\ul{i_s} + \frac{d}{dt}\ul{\Psi_s}
  +j\omega_k\underline{\Psi_s}\\
  \ul{\Psi_s}=l_s\ul{i_s}+\ul{\Psi_m}\\
  \omega_m=\omega_s\\
}


\end{document}
```

nice code :)

Comment: which in turn makes your code harder to read and harder to maintain. The env route is more preferable.